# First row in Dashing dashboard not aligned

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, dashing

I have this problem: As you can see in the picture below, I am using a layout that has only one element in the first row **but it has this weird right alignment issue (it extends too far right)**.

[image]

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/kbfubSYM)
[CSS](http://pastebin.com/mVtjXFa5)

**What is the problem?**

Here is my first element:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="15" data-sizey="3" >
  <div data-id="some-id" data-view="MyWidget" data-title="Some title" style="background-color:#749396"></div>
</li>
```

I am using this setup in `application.coffee` (15 columns, 9 rows, each column/row is 100 pixels wide):

```
Dashing.on 'ready', ->
  Dashing.widget_margins ||= [5, 5]
  Dashing.widget_base_dimensions ||= [100, 100]
  Dashing.numColumns ||= 15
```

When I specifically set the width on the `li`, it works.

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="15" data-sizey="3" style="width: 1640px;">
```

Here is the complete dashboard layout:

```
<% content_for :title do %>Dashboard<% end %>
<div class="gridster">
  <ul>

    <!-- Hack: Setting width of top row to 1640px! -->

    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="15" data-sizey="3" style="width: 1640px;">
      <div data-id="id1" data-view="OwnWidget" style="background-color:#749396"></div>
    </li>

    <li data-row="4" data-col="1" data-sizex="5" data-sizey="4">
      <div data-id="id2" data-view="Meter" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
    </li>

    <li data-row="4" data-col="6" data-sizex="5" data-sizey="4">
      <div data-id="id3" data-view="Number" style="background-color:#749396"></div>
    </li>

    <li data-row="4" data-col="11" data-sizex="5" data-sizey="4">
      <div data-id="id4" data-view="Number" style="background-color:#749396"></div>
    </li>

    <li data-row="8" data-col="1" data-sizex="5" data-sizey="4">
      <div data-id="id5" data-view="Meter" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
    </li>

    <li data-row="8" data-col="6" data-sizex="5" data-sizey="4">
      <div data-id="id6" data-view="Number" style="background-color:#749396"></div>
    </li>

    <li data-row="8" data-col="11" data-sizex="5" data-sizey="4">
      <div data-id="id7" data-view="Number" style="background-color:#749396"></div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the other `<li>`'s?

Comment: Added the whole layout.

Comment: Have you tried to get different results if you change ` Dashing.widget_base_dimensions ||= [100, 300]` and assign the rows according to their real rows `data-row="1"` and `data-row="2"` for the second. I could imagine that it calculates the margins the wrong way.

I see that you want to use different heights, but it might help to figure out the problem.

Comment: Everything works fine height-wise. If I put in another element in the first row, the margins will be calculated correctly, both horizontally and vertically. The problem only shows when you have a *single* element in the first row.

Comment: can u share any link?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide a hosted example right now.

Comment: Could you post an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'll provide the css. A jsfiddle example perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the same question in the Dashing forum, I got this very satisfying answer:

https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/339

Answer (score 3):

Without any CSS code, I cannot help you any further than below:

The issue seems to be caused by padding adjustment issues. Try writing this:

```
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This **MAY** (no definites here) fix your problem, as it counts padding using subtraction - not addition, which may fix your problem.

Here's an article on `box-sizing`  from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing, and one from CSS-Tricks http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/. They should be able to help you further in determining the problem.

Post some CSS code! We could then help you further.

Comment: I think this is right, but it wouldn't explain the lack of padding on the right columns? If they all use the same code, wouldn't all the elements have the extra padding?

Comment: @RichPeck Not necessarily - the elements that exist inside the elements are different, aren't they? They probably have different amounts of margin, padding, width, etc., and therefore cause the deviation. The elements themselves can be the same, but when their content is different and the margins of the elements in the contents are different, then you will get varying widths and heights (widths in the OP's case).

Comment: Possibly, but I'd still expect similar behavior if it was a fluid interface; if it's hard-coded widths, then your answer is probably right

Comment: @RichPeck It doesn't have to be a fluid interface - it just needs varying content.

Comment: I did not post any CSS because it is the standard Dashing-generated CSS (I also did not create a JSFiddle because this is not just some static website, it is a whole client/server web app). When I applied the CSS you provided, it did not help, though. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @meilke An online demo would give you the answer straightaway (as then we can easily take a look for you)

Comment: @meilke Why don't you view the source of that page and paste it on PasteBin or something? We could still help you, and it's equivalent to pasting your code.

Comment: I added links to the static HTML and generated CSS (see initial post).

Comment: @meilke I can't see anything wrong with that code (I put it in JSFiddle and took a look).

Comment: Of course not. It has the fixed width hack applied.

Comment: @meilke I don't understand then - have you fixed it?

Comment: I am talking about the hack in the original post.